# Free shipping countdown, need helping making it auto refresh

Tags: ajax, shopify, shopping-cart

I recently added a minor feature to the slide out shopping cart on a Shopify site to show the customer how many more items they need to add to their cart to receive free shipping. It works just fine, however the issue is that if a customer updates their quantity from the cart, then the feature doesn't automatically update and show that they qualify for free shipping. The customer would have to refresh the page or go to another page to see the update.

How can I make this automatically update?

```
{% assign free_quantity = 2 %}

{% assign cart_total = cart.item_count %}

{% assign cart_qty_left = free_quantity | minus: cart_total %}



<p class="tt-cart__add-on-title tt-text-2">

  {% if cart_qty_left > 0 %}

  You are {{ cart_qty_left }} item away from free shipping! 

  {% else %}

    You've got free shipping!

  {% endif %}

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest solution is to make an AJAX request to the current page and replace the content.

For example:

```
fetch(window.location.href).then(r => r.text()).then(res => {
    const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, 'text/html');
    const cartText = html.querySelector('.tt-cart__add-on-title').innerText;
    document.querySelector('.tt-cart__add-on-title').innerText = cartText
})
```

Where we make a request to the current URL address with `fetch(window.location.href)`, then we convert the response to text via `.then(r => r.text())`.

After that we create a DOMParser of the response text:

`const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, 'text/html');`

We grab the text from the parsed html targeting the proper element:

`const cartText = html.querySelector('.tt-cart__add-on-title').innerText;`

And finally we replace the text that is present on the page with the text we got from the response with:

`document.querySelector('.tt-cart__add-on-title').innerText = cartText`

This should happen on a specific event when you add products to the cart or update them.

Comment: Thanks for this drip. Where do I enter this? Would this go on the same liquid file that the original code lives in?

Comment: @EricFox this need to go in your javascript logic. You will need to create a change event and add this logic there. If you don't understand me it will be best to contact an agency to help you with this.